# How to format this mysql full join output with Array.prototype.reduce()

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this data that came from a full join query - that’s why the repeated data on each object inside the array.

```
[
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "1414-2",
    firstExam: 6,
    secondExam: 4.8,
    thirdExam: 7.0,
    teacher: "Hector M."
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "1515-2",
    firstExam: 7,
    secondExam: 5.6,
    thirdExam: 6.2,
    teacher: "Hector M."
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "1616-2",
    firstExam: 5,
    secondExam: 5.2,
    thirdExam: 5.5,
    teacher: "Hector M."
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "1717-2",
    firstExam: 5.5,
    secondExam: 6.7,
    thirdExam: 6.7,
    teacher: "Hector M."
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "1818-2",
    firstExam: 5.5,
    secondExam: 5.6,
    thirdExam: 6.6,
    teacher: "Hector M."
  },
  {
    id: 92,
    course: "Spanish",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "1919-2",
    firstExam: 5.6,
    secondExam: 7.0,
    thirdExam: 4.5,
    teacher: "Margarita R."
  },
  {
    id: 92,
    course: "Spanish",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "2020-2",
    firstExam: 6.1,
    secondExam: 6.5,
    thirdExam: 5.6,
    teacher: "Margarita R."
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "2121-2",
    firstExam: 5.2,
    secondExam: 5.4,
    thirdExam: 5.6,
    teacher: "Hector M."
  },
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentID: "2222-2",
    firstExam: 4.6,
    secondExam: 4.5,
    thirdExam: 5.4,
    teacher: "Hector M."
  }
];
```

Basically, it is the name of the course + some extra course data, and then the grades of 1 student + the teacher who gave the examen.

I need this data to end up like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 91,
    course: "History",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentsAndGrades: [
      {
        studentID: "2222-2",
        firstExam: 4.6,
        secondExam: 4.5,
        thirdExam: 5.4,
        teacher: "Hector M."
      },
      {
        studentID: "2121-2",
        firstExam: 5.2,
        secondExam: 5.4,
        thirdExam: 5.6,
        teacher: "Hector M."
      },
      {
        studentID: "1818-2",
        firstExam: 5.5,
        secondExam: 5.6,
        thirdExam: 6.6,
        teacher: "Hector M."
      },
      {
        studentID: "1717-2",
        firstExam: 5.5,
        secondExam: 6.7,
        thirdExam: 6.7,
        teacher: "Hector M."
      },
      {
        studentID: "1616-2",
        firstExam: 5,
        secondExam: 5.2,
        thirdExam: 5.5,
        teacher: "Hector M."
      },
      {
        studentID: "1515-2",
        firstExam: 7,
        secondExam: 5.6,
        thirdExam: 6.2,
        teacher: "Hector M."
      },
      {
        studentID: "1414-2",
        firstExam: 6,
        secondExam: 4.8,
        thirdExam: 7.0,
        teacher: "Hector M."
      }
    ] 
  },
  {
    id: 92,
    course: "Spanish",
    registerDate: '20-01-2020',
    endDate: '20-01-2020',
    studentsAndGrades: [
      {
        studentID: "2020-2",
        firstExam: 6.1,
        secondExam: 6.5,
        thirdExam: 5.6,
        teacher: "Margarita R."
      },
      {
        studentID: "1919-2",
        firstExam: 5.6,
        secondExam: 7.0,
        thirdExam: 4.5,
        teacher: "Margarita R."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried some reduce algorithms but I can't get it right. Here is the last one in a sandbox -> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/reduce-mysql-join-87s70).

Regards.

Comment: Please add some relevant code examples (attemps) to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reduce routine should give the desired result.

It checks if an item with id number exists in the accumulator. If not create a new template and after that fill the template with the student data.

```js
function reduceData(input){
  return input.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
    let itemId = acc.findIndex(item => item.id == curr.id);
    if (itemId == -1)
    {
      acc.push({id : curr.id, course : curr.course, registerDate : curr.registerDate, endDate : curr.endDate, studentsAndGrades : []});
      itemId = acc.length-1;
    }
    acc[itemId].studentsAndGrades.push({studentID : curr.studentID, teacher : curr.teacher, firstExam : curr.firstExam, secondExam : curr.secondExam, thirdExam : curr.thirdExam}); 
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

//all the data
const dataInput = [{
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "1414-2",
  firstExam: 6,
  secondExam: 4.8,
  thirdExam: 7.0,
  teacher: "Hector M."
}, {
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "1515-2",
  firstExam: 7,
  secondExam: 5.6,
  thirdExam: 6.2,
  teacher: "Hector M."
}, {
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "1616-2",
  firstExam: 5,
  secondExam: 5.2,
  thirdExam: 5.5,
  teacher: "Hector M."
}, {
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "1717-2",
  firstExam: 5.5,
  secondExam: 6.7,
  thirdExam: 6.7,
  teacher: "Hector M."
}, {
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "1818-2",
  firstExam: 5.5,
  secondExam: 5.6,
  thirdExam: 6.6,
  teacher: "Hector M."
}, {
  id: 92,
  course: "Spanish",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "1919-2",
  firstExam: 5.6,
  secondExam: 7.0,
  thirdExam: 4.5,
  teacher: "Margarita R."
}, {
  id: 92,
  course: "Spanish",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "2020-2",
  firstExam: 6.1,
  secondExam: 6.5,
  thirdExam: 5.6,
  teacher: "Margarita R."
}, {
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "2121-2",
  firstExam: 5.2,
  secondExam: 5.4,
  thirdExam: 5.6,
  teacher: "Hector M."
}, {
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentID: "2222-2",
  firstExam: 4.6,
  secondExam: 4.5,
  thirdExam: 5.4,
  teacher: "Hector M."
}];

console.log(reduceData(dataInput));
```

```css
  [ {
  id: 91,
  course: "History",
  registerDate: '20-01-2020',
  endDate: '20-01-2020',
  studentsAndGrades: [ {
    studentID: "2222-2", firstExam: 4.6, secondExam: 4.5, thirdExam: 5.4, teacher: "Hector M."
  }
  ,
```

```html
<span>
```